# Set up svn for an existing project

Tags: ubuntu, subversion

I have an existing project “abc” with the path `/home/abc`. I want to set up a subversion repository in Ubuntu for this project. I have already installed subversion with the help the article “[Setting Up an Ubuntu Subversion Server](http://odyniec.net/articles/ubuntu-subversion-server/)”. I did not understand the checkout portion and how to connect SVN to my “abc” project.

Comment: Also consider mercurial (hg), for most use cases it is better than svn.

Comment: Look at http://hginit.com for quick start on Mercurial.

Comment: At this time being I need to setup svn .When i open svn repo through browser it's shows me 403 forbidden error

Comment: to be able to access an svn repository using web browser you will need to setup webdav+apache (or your preferential web server), if you setup apache you will also need to setupbasic authentication on apache side .

Answer (score 1):

Assume you svn server URI is `svn://yourhost/your_repo` (or `https://yourdomain.com/your_repo`, if you're using WebDAV):

```
$ cd /home
$ svn import abc svn://yourhost/your_repo/abc -m "Initial commit message."
$ mv abc abc.bak
$ svn checkout svn://yourhost/your_repo/abc
```

Check that everything has been imported successfully and that you can checkout your code. Once you've verified that everything is okay, you can remove your backup:

```
$ rm -rf abc.bak
```

(**BE CAREFUL--Keep your backup somewhere just in case!**)

Now, `/home/abc/` is a working copy of the `your_repo` repository.

Comment: when i access my svn repo through browser it's shows You don't have permission to access /svn/coderepository on this server

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see the guide you mention because it is blocked in my workplace.

You must first create a project before you check it out, so do `svnadmin create abc1`. This will create a repository for you. I hope you have the privileges to access the newly created repo. Next, do `svn co file://home/abc1` or `svn co http://home/abc1` (if it is behind a webserver), then cp files from `/home/abc` to `/home/abc1`,`svn add /home/abc1` and `svn ci -m "whatever comment you put"`.

If this is not clear, please add some more information to your question and I will try to help further.

Comment: When I access my svn repo through browser it's shows You don't have permission to access /svn/coderepository on this server. as you mention before please help me how can I setup apache for that.

Comment: have you setup apache or any other webserver to serve the svn repository , if so can you share your configuration?

Comment: In apache.conf file svn portion is commented                    # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet

#<Location /svn>
 # DAV svn
 # SVNParentPath /home/svn
 # AuthType Basic
 # AuthName "My SVN Repositories"
 # AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth
 # Require valid-user
#</Location>

Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf

Comment: 1) is webdav loaded on apache configuration, also have you created a password for accessing this over http if not `htpasswd2 -c /etc/subversion/passwd [username]`

Comment: webdav is not loaded .Password is all ready created

Comment: if you are keeping your repositories in /home like `/home/abc` keep your SVN ParentPath /home , what does your error log say about password attempt ? does it say permission denied or something else. can you paste some log from error_log and access_log ?

Comment: [Mon Jun 16 12:47:43.984547 2014] [authz_svn:error] [pid 6947] [client 122.176.97.151:4081] Access denied: 'coderepository' GET coderepository:/

Comment: what is the permission on /home ? may be move svn repositories out of /home and move to /var/www/svn or something and give 777 to rule out dir level permission issue.

Comment: in '/home' permission is 755. and svn path is /home/coderepository/svn/coderepository all folder are given 755 permission.svn admin command is running in /home/coderepository/svn/coderepository.  apache svn parent path is                 <Location /svn>        
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /home/svn/
  AuthName "My SVN Repositories"
  AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth
  Require valid-user
</Location>                                                      In coderepository svn parent path is                <Location /svn>
DAV svn
SVNParentPath /home/coderepository/svn
</Location>

Comment: try putting 777 -R /home and see if this resolves and validate your username and password once again, because either dir permission or user login failure only can cause 403 error

Comment: I am sure that it is not a password issues. I also change permission recursive all file to 777 but not getting expected result

Comment: how are you sure about username and password, do you have something on log ?

Comment: because when I given wrong username or pass it showing different error.